# How to exclude a sub folder from ignore

Tags: unison

I have a `build` folder that I want to ignore and inside that build folder, I have a `generated-src` that I don't want to ignore

`` root
  | - build
    | - lib
    | - bin
    ` - generated-src
  | - src
  ` - tst ``

I tried with this syntax:

```
ignorenot = Path */build/generated-src/*
ignorenot = Path */build/generated-src
ignore = Name */build/*
ignore = Name */build
```

But it does not work and according to the [documentation](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html), this is kind of expected

> In particular, putting ignore = Path * in your profile and then using ignorenot to select particular paths to be synchronized will not work

But I still need to do something like this, I though to use Regex to specify the `ignore` part, but I am not sure how to build it. Maybe can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Well, my problem was a bit more complex, and also my build folder was actually a symbolic link. Finally I end up doing this:

```
# Ignore build folder from the workplace and the package.
# Keep the src-generated sync so you build only on one side.
ignore = Path */build/*
ignore = Path */build
follow = Path */*/*/build
ignore = Path */*/*/build/*
ignorenot = Path */*/*/build/generated-src
```

The trick is that `Path` takes **exact** path, so the globing part is only about the naming, and you need to specific the exact depth of the folder. So `ignore = Path */*/*/build/*` will ignore everything in the folder, but `ignorenot = Path */*/*/build/generated-src` will work as expected. So same thing with `Name` as I did before, does not work.